# access rows that are found in two columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-analysis

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXtRy.png)[*Car sells data*]

from the image, how do access rows that are expensive and too old?

"dataset[dataset['Price_description']=='Expensive' & dataset['Car_health']=='Too old']"

that was my code but its wrong, please try and correct me

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the two equality statements in parentheses:

```
dataset[(dataset['Price_description']=='Expensive') & (dataset['Car_health']=='Too old')]
```

Or use `eg`:

```
dataset[dataset['Price_description'].eq('Expensive') & dataset['Car_health'].eq('Too old')]
```

Comment: Can you convert to wiki?

Comment: @jezrael sure if it makes you happy ;)

Comment: Only surprise why not closed.

Comment: Because it was faster to answer than searching for a potential dupe. I close most of the ones for which I know what to search for

Comment: check my profile, there are most repeated dupes.

Comment: @jezrael I know, it's just something I make the effort to search, sometimes not. But I feel that you're doing also the same (example: [yours](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71657581/16343464) and [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62721565/split-the-data-frame-based-on-consecutive-row-values-differences), I picked one but there are many others) ;)

Comment: yes, please give me know, because I sometimes failed too.

Comment: dupe failed, because non numeric column.

Comment: I am sure there is one, it's so common, just lazy to search

Comment: If close like dupe and there is my answer, please let me know it for wiki answer.

Comment: it's not really my way, I don't want to "police"

Comment: hmmm, it is up to you. But for me is sad if blatant dupe answers are answered high rep users(sometimes also by me). So I am grateful for closing and feedback.